# Adding a custom JavaFX control to Scenebuilder

Tags: java, javafx, custom-controls, scenebuilder, richtextfx

Currently, i'm building a project within FXML and would like to make use of a custom RichTextFX Java class within SceneBuilder 2.0. I know that it will involve the use of custom controls however I'm currently confused on what steps I'll need to actually complete the implementation.

```
package view;

public class LeftTextArea extends TextArea {

private CodeArea leftCode = new CodeArea();

//CodeArea -  defining the areas for coloured text:
 private static final String[] KEYWORDS = new String[] {
            "Given", "Then", "And", "But", "Feature", "Scenario", "When", "Background"
 };

 private static final String KEYWORD_PATTERNS = "\\b(" + String.join("|", KEYWORDS) + ")\\b";

 private static final String SEMICOLON = "\\;";

 private static final String STRING = "\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"";

 private static final String BRACKET =  "\\[|\\]";

 private static final String PARENTHESIS = "\\(|\\)";


 //CodeArea - Defining the pattern used for the Keywords using Regex commands:

 //CodeArea - Compiling the pattern using the Java Regex Pattern class:
 private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
           "(?<KEYWORD>" + KEYWORD_PATTERNS + ")"
         + "|(?<SEMICOLON>" + SEMICOLON + ")"
         + "|(?<STRING>" + STRING + ")"
         + "|(?<BRACKET>" + BRACKET + ")"
         + "|(?<PARENTHESIS>" + PARENTHESIS + ")"
         );

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    leftCode.setParagraphGraphicFactory(LineNumberFactory.get(leftCode));
    leftCode.richChanges().filter(ch -> !ch.getInserted().equals(ch.getRemoved())).subscribe(change -> {
    leftCode.setStyleSpans(0, computeHighlighting(leftCode.getText()));
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(leftCode, 500, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(LeftTextArea.class.getResource("GherkinView.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private static StyleSpans<Collection<String>> computeHighlighting(String text) {
    Matcher patternmatcher = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    StyleSpansBuilder<Collection<String>> spansBuilder = new StyleSpansBuilder<>();

    int keywordend = 0;

    while(patternmatcher.find()) {
        String styleClass = 
        patternmatcher.group("KEYWORD") != null ? "keyword" :
        patternmatcher.group("SEMICOLON") != null ? "semicolon" : 
        patternmatcher.group("STRING") != null ? "string" : 
        patternmatcher.group("BRACKET")!= null ? "bracket" : 
        patternmatcher.group("PARENTHESIS")!= null ? "parenthesis" :
        null;
        assert styleClass != null;
        spansBuilder.add(Collections.emptyList(), patternmatcher.start() - keywordend);
        spansBuilder.add(Collections.singleton(styleClass), patternmatcher.end() - patternmatcher.start());
        keywordend = patternmatcher.end();
    }
    spansBuilder.add(Collections.emptyList(), text.length() - keywordend);
    return spansBuilder.create();
}
}
```

I've tried to export it as a JAR file and import it into SceneBuilder, however, it's un-editable and does not function as intended. This is how it looks on the final product[JavaFX GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhU8L.png).

Any help would be appreciated and I'd be more than happy to clarify further.

Thanks,

Charandeep

Comment: Go to the cog where you imported the custom component and then go to *Custom Library Folder* -> *Show JAR Analysis Report*. If there is any output, I'm sure it would be helpful to anyone here trying to answer your question.